# Python3 - tar - Добавить все файлы в тек.директории в архив

Tags: python, tar

Oc Ubuntu 16.04 
Каким образом правильно добавить все файлы из текущей папки в архив?
Читал мануал , нашел 2 способа.
Вопрос, есть ли более правильный способ ?
Либо что - то вроде такого tar.addall

1 й способ

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("tar/sample.tar.gz", "w:gz")
for name in ["./"]:
    tar.add(name)
tar.close()
```

2 й способ

```
import tarfile
import subprocess

subprocess.call('python3 -m tarfile -c tar/sample.tar.gz *', shell=True)
```

Вопрос, есть что-то другое или являются ли эти 2 способа корректными для этой задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заархивировать текущую директорию в `tar/sample.tar.gz`:

```
import shutil 

shutil.make_archive('tar/sample', 'gztar')
```