# Python: Почему программа не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа запускается без ошибок, но не выполняет копирование файлов. Директории указаны существующие. В чем может быть ошибка?

ОС Windows 7, если это имеет значение.

UPD: Проблема решена, нужно было дописать r при помещении файла в архив.

```
zip_command = r"zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))



import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\Code']
# Для имен, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'C:\\Backup'

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: а это `print(zip_command)` точно запустить команду? на мой взгляд просто напечатает.

Comment: То, что в `zip_command` руками выполняется?

Comment: я вижу пробел в имени файла target

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, там `os.system`

Comment: Спасибо, пробел убрала, но результат тот же.

Comment: zip_command должен с программой выполняться @vp_arth

Comment: Вы выводите его на экран, следовательно видите, какая команда должна выполняться. **Внимание, вопрос**: выполняется ли эта команда, если вы скопируете её и выполните вручную, в терминале?

Comment: уберите ключ `q` из `zip_command`, посмотрите, что выводит в консоль команда `zip`

Comment: выводит информацию по zip @ЭдуардИзмалков

Comment: zip_command из консоли работает, только с программой не выполняется, может, нужно в программе выполнить? @ЭдуардИзмалков

Comment: если из zip_command убрать q, что выводится?

Comment: извините, в первый раз не поняла вопрос. выводится adding: Code/ <236 bytes security> <stored 0%> и т. д.

Comment: а что именно в "и т.д."? приведённая Вами строка - это добавление каталога, ниже должен идти как раз перечень архивируемых файлов. если они не архивируются, то там и должна быть указана ошибка.

Comment: adding: Code/09city.py <172 bytes security> <deflated 68%> другие файлы так же, они архивируются? @ЭдуардИзмалков

Comment: тогда даже не знаю, что Вам сказать. судя по выводу архив создаётся без ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду искать ответ дальше. @ЭдуардИзмалков

Comment: Попробуйте перенаправить весь вывод в файл - это поможет понять источник проблемы. Пример: `zip_command = r"zip -r {0} {1} > c:\temp\out.txt 2>&1".format(target, ' '.join(source))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему не сделать так

```
import os
import zipfile
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Backup.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

path = 'test_dir'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
zipf.close()
```

Comment: или так: [shutil.make_archive('C:\\Backup\\{:%Y%m%d %H%M%S}'.format(datetime.now()), 'zip', 'C:\\Code', dry_run=True)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611804/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How do I zip the contents of a folder using python (version 2.5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/296499/4279)