# Как правильно создать tar архив?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать tar архив средствами Python:

```
import os
import tarfile


def create_tar(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))


create_tar('/sdcard/private.tar', 'data/images')
```

Этот код работает. Но создается архив private.tar в котором находится еще один архив private.tar. В последнем уже находятся упакованые файлы. То есть вид архива такой:

```
private.tar
         private.tar
                 file.txt
                 file_2.txt
```

Как создать архив без одноименного архива внутри?

Comment: Или `:gz` уберите, или расширение поставьте `.tar.gz`

Comment: Верно. Сделайте ответом.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python3 - tar - Добавить все файлы в тек.директории в архив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611778/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что упаковать все файлы из `data/images` папки (рекусивно) в `/sdcard/private.tar.gz` архив:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil

shutil.make_archive('/sdcard/private', 'gztar', 'data/images')
```

[`shutil.make_archive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive)  может принимать ещё несколько параметров.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ваш код сработал на python 3

```
import os
import tarfile


def create_tar(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))

create_tar('/tmp/private.tar', '/tmp/test_dir')
```

---

```
tar -tf private.tar 
test_dir/
test_dir/2.py
```

---

```
ls test_dir/
2.py
```